# how do i attach an icon to a file when sending it to someone so it shows the icon when they download it?

Tags: python, icons

so I want to send my friend a file I made but I don't know how to make it have the icon already applied to the shortcut. I can tell him to make a shortcut and apply the icon manually, but I would rather know how to make it more "app-like".
its a python file if it matters.

Comment: There is no cross-platform way to do this. Are you targeting Windows?

Comment: yes, working on windows, for windows